# Get language in a tpl file

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to write a code in different languages ​​using an

> if (language = en || lenguage=es) {// code } (For example)

in a tpl file. How can I know what language the user is using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In front office use the lang_iso variable:

```
{if $lang_iso == 'en'}code{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Prestashop 1.7 it seems that the correct way to read the iso code of the current language is

```
{$language.iso_code}
```

To find out all the properties of the object:

```
{$language|@var_dump}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the language i uses:

```
{$cookie->id_lang}
```

You could use:

```
{if $cookie->id_lang == '<id_language>'} {/if}
```